# SQL query to extract some rows from one row of a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE company (
    id integer auto_increment primary key
    company_name varchar(50),
    category_1 varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    category_2 varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    category_3 varchar(50) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO company VALUES ('apple', 'mobile', 'pc', 'gadget');
```

How can I make a query that returns:

```
    1, 'apple', 'mobile'
    2, 'apple', 'pc'
    3, 'apple', 'gadget'
```

Comment: Well the best option would be to normalize the table and create an associated table to hold categories i.e. one to many relation.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Yes, of course. But this is not mine db, i need to retrieve data only. I cannot change relationships.

Comment: your create table is missing a `,` after `id integer auto_increment primary key` . I know this is just a small manual error  :) also the `Insert` query has syntax error .

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UNION` :

```
SELECT id, company_name, category_1 FROM company
UNION
SELECT id + 1, company_name, category_2 FROM company
UNION
SELECT id + 2, company_name, category_3 FROM company
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04e58/2)

Comment: That made the trick. Thank you. I had the same query, but unfortunately have not seen the right result. Now it is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Solution given by notulysses is good and would solve your problem. but if you add more rows your query might become bulkier hence written different solution.

Assuming below is set up

**CREATE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE company (
id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
company_name VARCHAR(50),
category_1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
category_2 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
category_3 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

**Data Insertion**

```
INSERT INTO company(company_name ,category_1 ,category_2 ,category_3 ) VALUES ('apple', 'mobile', 'pc', 'gadget');
INSERT INTO company(company_name ,category_1 ,category_2 ,category_3 ) VALUES ('Samsung', 'mobile', 'pc', 'gadget');
INSERT INTO company(company_name ,category_1 ,category_2 ,category_3 ) VALUES ('microsoft', 'mobile', 'pc', 'gadget');
```

**SQL Solution to generate ID dynamically**

```
SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS id, company_name,products FROM (  
  SELECT company_name ,(SELECT Category_1 FROM company c2 WHERE c2.company_name =c1.company_name ) products FROM company c1
  UNION  
  SELECT company_name ,(SELECT Category_2 FROM company c2 WHERE c2.company_name =c1.company_name ) products FROM company c1
  UNION 
  SELECT company_name ,(SELECT Category_3 FROM company c2 WHERE c2.company_name =c1.company_name ) products FROM company c1
  ) T ,(SELECT @row_number:=0) rowNum
  ORDER BY company_name
```

If you run this query you would get below output

```
    id  company_name  products
------  ------------  --------
     1  apple         mobile  
     2  apple         pc      
     3  apple         gadget  
     4  microsoft     pc      
     5  microsoft     gadget  
     6  microsoft     mobile  
     7  Samsung       mobile  
     8  Samsung       pc      
     9  Samsung       gadget
```

Please let me know if it solves your problem